# Updating status on twitter in android

Tags: android, twitter, parse-platform

I am trying to integrate twitter in android.I logged into twitter as a parse user but can't update my status as i'm now getting a forbidden 403 error .What may be the reason for 403 error and how to rectify it?Any help would be appreciated..
My code is

```
public void twitterbtnClick(View v)
{
    ParseTwitterUtils.logIn(this, new LogInCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseUser arg0, com.parse.ParseException arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (arg0 == null) {
                  Log.d("MyApp", "Uh oh. The user cancelled the Twitter login.");
                } else if (arg0.isNew()) {
                  Log.d("MyApp", "User signed up and logged in through Twitter!");
                  TweetsTask task = new TweetsTask();
                  task.execute("Hi buddies");
                } else {
                  Log.d("MyApp", "User logged in through Twitter!");
                  TweetsTask task = new TweetsTask();
                  task.execute("Hi buddies");
                }
        }
        });

}
public class TweetsTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected  String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("Parameter",""+params[0]);


        HttpClient client =new DefaultHttpClient();
        String status = params[0];
        Log.d("Status",""+status);
        List<NameValuePair> parameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mystring", status));
        Log.d("Parameter2",""+status);
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json");
        try {
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        ParseTwitterUtils.getTwitter().signRequest(httppost);
        try {
            HttpResponse response =   client.execute(httppost);
             if(response==null){
                 task="fail";

             }else{
                 task="success";

             }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        return task;
    }

}
 protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    if(task.equals("success"))
    {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
         Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext()," error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
   }
```

Comment: Where is your code ? Where is your error?

Comment: Haven't worked with android, but are you using Twitter Developer credentials that allow read, write and access? (By default creds are read only.)

Comment: @arilaan im using parse.com to login to twitter and given access type as read,write and access direct messages in application type

Comment: @GrIsHu Actually there is no error but my twitter status is not being updated and when debugged showed forbidden 403.How to overcome this?Plz help..

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a high enough reputation to comment on user2853201's question but from looking at the code. The NameValuePair parameter "mystring" in the code  should be changed to "status". And from the twitter documentation, the "403" error occurs when you try and send a duplicate tweet.

Here's how I sent a tweet using Parse:

This is the OnClickListener() method for my twitter button:

```
        btnTwitter.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
          public void onClick(View arg0) {
             ShareViaTwitter();

            }
         });
```

The ShareViaTwitter() method:

```
 private void displayShareTwitter (){

 ParseTwitterUtils.logIn(this, new LogInCallback() {

    @Override
    public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           if (user == null) {
                  Log.d("MyApp", "Uh oh. The user cancelled the Twitter login.");
                } else if (user.isNew()) {
                  Log.d("MyApp", "User signed up and logged in through Twitter!");
                  new sendTweet().execute("your twitter status update");
                } else {
                  Log.d("MyApp", "User logged in through Twitter!");
                  new sendTweet().execute("your twitter status update");
                }

    }
    });


    }
```

The sendTweet inner class:

```
 class sendTweet extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    boolean success = true; 
    @Override
    protected  String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String status = params[0];
            List<NameValuePair> parameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            //This is where you add all the parameters you need for your tweet,
            //see "https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/statuses/update" 
            //for all the optional parameters you can add here
            parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("status", status));
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json"); //API used here 1.1
            try {
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters));
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                success = false;
                    e.printStackTrace();
            } 

            ParseTwitterUtils.getTwitter().signRequest(httppost);//This seems to cause the app to ask for authorization each time I tweet
            HttpResponse response =   client.execute(httppost);             
        } catch (Exception e) {
            success = false; 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

 protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

     if (success){
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"sent tweet",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }else{
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"tweet failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }


   }
```

}